# Can I use merge statement with linked server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to use `MERGE` statement with a linked server table in my SQL server 2012.

My query is:

```
MERGE [linkedservername].[databasename].[schema].[tablename] as T
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

As is said here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx, `target_table` cannot be a remote table. `target_table` cannot have any rules defined on it.